# PHP Break WHILE loop from another file

Tags: php

I have some code where I need to break out from a `while` loop where the loop requires a file, but I want the file to be able to `break` the loop somehow.

Example code

app.php

```
<?php

  set_time_limit( 0 );

  while ( true ) {

    require('response.php');

  }

?>
```

response.php

```
<?php

  if( rand(0, 999) === 534 ){

    break;

  }

?>
```

But it errors out like this:

> Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in response.php on line 5

Another example:

loop.php

```
<?php

  while ( true ) {

     require('break.php');

  }

?>
```

break.php

```
<?php

  const $break = true;

  if( $break ){

    break;

  }

?>
```

Which returns the same error, but on different line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `boolean` variable to break the loop in first file like this:

**app.php**

```
<?php
set_time_limit( 0 );

$blnContinue = true;
while ( true && $blnContinue ) {
    require('response.php');
}
?>
```

**response.php**

```
<?php
if( rand(0, 999) === 534 ){
    $blnContinue = false;
}
?>
```

Comment: I will set this to correct answer due to it solved my question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try to set variabile as break in response.php an then interrupt the script by return:

```
$break_while=1;
return;
```

Then in app.php check if this variabile exists:

```
if(isset($break_while)) break;
```

It should work, the break will happen when the response.php execure the return (so it stops) and PHP checks in app.php for $break_while.

Comment: Great solution, but in some files I want it to break in middle of code on failure, so for my use it won't work..

Comment: Using `return;` would also return from a function, so if any of my statements is inside a function this wouldn't work either.. Sorry pal